# Options for adding a minor feature to a crate that necessitates a new dependency

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

I want to add a relatively small feature to crate `A` which necessitates depending on a second crate `B`. `A`'s maintainer reasonably objects about introducing a whole new dependency for a small, although potentially useful, feature.

What are the best ways of handling this? The options I can think of are:

1. make a new crate with the new feature (with dependencies on both `A` and `B`)
2. use Cargo "features" somehow so users have to opt in to the extra dependency.

**1** seems suboptimal since it's a small feature that's pretty tied in to `A`, and it seems annoying to have to specially depend on a third crate, but **2** seems almost as bad...

Is there some way to compile my minor feature if and only if a crate explicitly depends on both `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 3):

This is [*exactly* the case optional features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section) solve:

> Cargo supports features to allow expression of:
>
> - conditional compilation options (usable through `cfg` attributes);
> - **optional dependencies, which enhance a package, but are not required**; and
> - clusters of optional dependencies, such as `postgres`, that would include the `postgres` package, the `postgres-macros` package, and
>     possibly other packages (such as development-time mocking libraries,
>     debugging tools, etc.).

Unfortunately, you seem to have already dismissed this option without any explanation as to why it's "almost bad", so... I guess the only option you have left is to fork the crate and apply your changes.

Comment: Oh sorry! The explanation (which may be wrong) that was in my head (but which I didn't express) was: features are opt in, meaning you have to explicitly ask for them, rather than it just being automatic if the right dependencies are satisfied. (Am I making sense?) So making another crate or instead using features each necessitate a user adding an extra blurb in their `Cargo.toml`.